# How to check if string is contained in an array in AutoHotKey

Tags: arrays, string, autohotkey, contains

I have following code:

```
ignored := [ "Rainmeter.exe", "Nimi Places.exe", "mumble.exe" ]

a := ignored.HasKey("mumble.exe")
MsgBox,,, %a%
```

It returns `0` even though the string is clearly present in the array.

**How do I test if a string value is present in an array?**

PS: I also tried `if var in` which gives same results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't, using just one command. Such functionality is not implemented in AHK_L as of 1.1.22.3.

You'll have to either define your own function

```
hasValue(haystack, needle) {
    if(!isObject(haystack))
        return false
    if(haystack.Length()==0)
        return false
    for k,v in haystack
        if(v==needle)
            return true
    return false
}
```

or use some fancy workaround:

```
ignored := { "Rainmeter.exe":0, "Nimi Places.exe":0, "mumble.exe":0 }
msgbox, % ignored.HasKey("mumble.exe")
```

This would create an associative array and put your values as keys (the values are set to 0 here), so the `.HasKey()` makes sense to use.