# AutoHotkey: Regex match Window title with dozens of variations

Tags: regex, autohotkey

Below is a shortened version of a script I have that's checking against the windows Title, and the number in the title determines what text is sent.

I'm wondering if I can incorporate an array of these numbers instead of having an increasingly large if/else statement, but still check against the windows title accurately.

```
Loop
{
WinWait, Windows security
WinGetTitle, Title, A
WinGetClass, Class, A
if (RegExMatch(Title, "Windows security: ") AND (Class == "Transparent Windows Client") OR RegExMatch(Title, "Windows security: ") AND (Class == "#32770")) 
{
    if (RegExMatch(Title, "Windows security: (049|064|067|071|077|158|193|210|214|215|221|224|239|... ENHANCE)+.*(POR|R.|WS.)+") AND (Class == "Transparent Windows Client") OR RegExMatch(Title, "Windows security: (049|064|067|071|077|158|193|210|214|215|221|224|239|... ENHANCE)+.*(POR|R.|WS.)+") AND (Class == "#32770"))
        {
        Send ExampleText{Enter}
}
}}
return
```

Comment: Yeah, why not. Also, with `SetTitleMatchMode RegEx` you can use regex:  `WinWait, Windows security ahk_class (Transparent Windows Client|#32770)`

Comment: @wOxxOm Wow, did not know you could use the RegEx elsewhere. That will certainly help to condense the code. As for incorporating the array with the RegEx, do you have any proposed solutions?

Comment: `(?:0(?:49|6[47]|7[17])|1(?:58|93)|2(?:1[045]|2[14]|39))` Give me the full list of numbers, I'll make a regex trie for you.

Comment: @sln While that's appreciated, that wouldn't be easily adjustable or expandable to the layman. The array method would be easier to modify for others using this, which is why it appears preferable to me.

Comment: I was only thinking if the _array_ doesn't change much, you could make it a constant string. No matter, there is software that does this for you or the layman. Here is a [175,000 word dictionary](http://www.regexformat.com/Dnl/_Samples/_Ternary_Tool%20(Dictionary)/___txt/_ASCII_175,000_word_Mix_A-Z_Multi_Lined.txt) constructed by a layman.

Comment: Do you care what the numbers are? You could just test for `\d+` to match any amount of numbers.

Comment: @Whothehellisthat Indeed I do. There are some 1400 entries this is working with. The subset I'm proposing being placed into an array elicits different behavior than all the other non-matching numbers.

Comment: You'll have to add all those numbers to the regex then, right? You can just format the "array" into `number|number` syntax and paste it in. If you're maintaining a list of those numbers, you could maintain them in that regex, I assume.

Comment: @Whothehellisthat The idea was to do the reverse, where instead of having the above code, I might be able to keep the desired numbers in an array and check against those. I was thinking akin to Python's `if x in ['049', '064', '067', '071']` but ultimately I'm just open to any way to simplify and condense the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, you have your array of valid numbers set like this

```
validNumbers := [ "049", "064", "067" ] ; etc..
```

You could split that RegEx statement in two steps and thus, work with an array:

```
valid:=false
for i,v in validNumbers ; there is no such thing as "if x in [...]" - http://stackoverflow.com/a/33593563/3779853
    if(inStr(Title,v))
        valid:=true
if(valid) {
    if(RegExMatch(Title, "Windows security: [0-9]+.*(POR|R.|WS.)+")) {
        ; ...
    }
}
```

This only matches against a "any-numbers"-regex when one of the numbers is contained somewhere in the title.

Another method might be constructing the large regex manually:

```
regex := "Windows security: ("
for i,v in validNumbers
    regex .= v "|"
regex .= ")+.*(POR|R.|WS.)+"
if(RegExMatch(Title, regex)) {
    ; ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a solution. So ultimately it appears that a solution that laymen will be able to maintain will be larger than one where I just create the regex, correct?

Comment: @DavidMetcalfe putting everything in the source code directly like you did will most probably be the most compressed solution you can get. the advantage here is, you could read the numbers from an external file, thus making the maintenance independent of source code